# String representation of std::vector<T>

Tags: c++, string, vector

Is it possible to implement a C++ function which gives a string representation of every `std::vector<T>`, as long as the element of type `T` can be appended to an output stream like

```
T x;
...
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

The string representation should look like

```
[x, y, z]
```

I've attempted the following, but what should `?` be?

```
template <typename T> std::string vectorToString(std::vector<T>& vec) {
    std::string s;
    for (T element : vec) {
        ?
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers

Comment: If you are interested in implementing this on your own, you probably want to learn about SFINAE, trailing decltype() and std::enable_if :) But it is doable, and it requires the tools above in order to detect at compile time if T is streamable.

Comment: I thinkl it would be better to change signature to const ref: vectorToString( **const** std::vector< T > & vec )

Comment: @bluescarni:I don't see why that would be necessary. If `T` isn't streamable the compiler would complain with an error somewhere in the function that it hasn't found any applicable `operator<<`. If you remove the function from the overload set for those cases it would complain that no applicable overload exists. So the only "advantage" of using `enable_if` would be a different, but probably worse, error-message. And why would you want to use trailing return? The test for streamability would best be written as a type trait anyways, so no need to use the parameters in the return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want a `stringstream` to do the formatting:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << '['
bool first = true;
for (T const & element : vec) {
    if (!first) {
        ss << ", ";
    }
    ss << element;
    first = false;
}
ss << ']';
return ss.str();
```

Comment: +1, but you probably want to take the element by reference to avoid unnecessary copying (since `operator<<` should never modify the original object): `for (T const & element : vec)`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Indeed; I copied that line from the question without applying my brain.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instance for `?` and return [`std::ostringstream::str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str):

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << "[";

for (auto i(vec.begin()); i != vec.end(); i++)
{
    if (vec.begin() != i) s << ", ";
    s << *i;
}
s << "]";

return s.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on C++11, you can use this simple version:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
string format(vector<T> const& v)
{
    if (v.empty()) return "[]";
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << "[" << v[0];
    for_each(begin(v) + 1, end(v), [&ss] (T const& s) { ss << ", " << s; });
    ss << "]";
    return ss.str();
}
```

If you want to make it generic for **other types of collections** (not just `vector`) or even for **sub-ranges of a collection**, you can generalize it this way:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename It>
string format(It b, It e)
{
    if (b == e) return "[]";
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << "[" << *b;
    for_each(++b, e, [&ss] (decltype(*b)& s) { ss << ", " << s; });
    ss << "]";
    return ss.str();
}

template<typename C>
string format(C const& c)
{
    return format(begin(c), end(c));
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = { 4, 5, 5, 8 };
    cout << format(v) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit faster version

```
template <typename T> std::string vectorToString( const std::vector<T>& vec ) {
    if ( vec.empty() ) {
        return "[]";
    }
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << "[" << vec.front();

    for (auto i = vec.begin() + 1, e = vec.end(); i != e; i++)
    {
        s << ", " << *i;
    }
    s << "]";

    return s.str();
}
```

Another moment: maybe it would be right to specialize this function for strings and quote them, because if a string in vector begins or ends with `,` it would be hard to understand how many strings was printed.

```
template <>
std::string vectorToString< std::string >( const std::vector<std::string>& vec ) {
    if ( vec.empty() ) {
        return "[]";
    }
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << "[" << vec.front();

    for (auto i = vec.begin() + 1, e = vec.end(); i != e; i++)
    {
        s << ", \"" << *i << "\"";
    }
    s << "]";

    return s.str();
}
```

Comment: But what if the element strings contain quotes?  Generation of CSV is a bit more complicated and one should use an existing library.

Answer (score 0):

Using algorithms, which usually simplify code (not sure if in this case, but added for the sake of completion):

```
template <typename T>
std::string toString( std::vector<T> const & v ) {
   if (v.empty()) 
      return "[]";
   typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator last = std::prev(v.end());
   std::ostringstream st;
   st << "[ ";
   std::copy( v.begin(), last, std::ostream_iterator<T>(st,", ") );
   st << *last << " ]";
   return st.str();
}
```